# How to hide parent component from routerview component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

How to hide or manage parent component from the routerview component?

Comment: Hi, and welcome on stackoverflow. 
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess to your question which is not fully documented is to apply a v-if tag at the root of what you don't want to show, where the condition of it is "this.$route.name === 'father-route-name'"

Comment: N.B You don't need the "this" in the template, but it was for letting you understand of what i was talking about